# How can i check Server not responding condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

In my app am getting data from a webserver using json. so each time i communicate with sever i would get a json and iam using it in right way.But some time my sever is down .Then how do i check whether the server is online or down before sending request from app other wise app will crash?

Please help me?

Comment: Why does the app crash?  That sounds like you are mishandling this common situation.

Comment: because in view didload methode it has to send request to server

Comment: Yeah, you are mishandling this condition.

Comment: @mango means doing `HTTP/Network Request ` in `main Thread.` ?

Comment: what you mean by mishandling?please let me know?

Comment: @bunty Madan : iam using HTTP  POST method

Comment: By mishandling I mean fix the reason for the crash.  This is the problem you are facing.

Comment: problem for crash is null json when server is offline

Comment: So how do you think you could handle that correctly?

Comment: Perhaps show come code. How do you send the request to the server, how to you read the response, how do you handle a timeout, where does the crash occur, ... ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this  ,setup a timer that cancels your connection(interation with server) after a specific time period

```
 connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate: self startImmediately:NO];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(onTimeExpired)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

[connection start];


// When time expires, cancel the connection
-(void)onTimeExpired
{
    [self.connection cancel];
}
```

so whenever server is not responding json will be null.Or even in low speed internet connectivity json will get corrupted so what iam suggesting is like cancel the connection if you are not able to connect with server.

Comment: This is a hack.  The OP should fix the reason for the app crash.

Comment: trojanfoe:mango mensioned that they are using json calls ,so whenever server is not responding json will be null.Or even in low speed internet connectivity json will get corrupted so what iam suggesting is like cancel the connection if you are not able to connect with server.

Comment: NSURLRequest already has a timeoutInterval parameter, which is 60 seconds by default. There should be no need to use another timer.

Comment: @mango... Martin is right just used the default one and in order to resolve the crash, man what you need to do, as the place where you not get response just redirect to some other page/screen... And, one more thing you can do is to get the response status code... Try it, and hope prob will be sorted out, and please let us know in any concern mate